# Convert time value to format “hh:mm Am/Pm” using Android

Tags: android, stringtokenizer, android-date

I am getting date value from database like "2013-02-27 06:06:30"
using StringTokenizer I will get time separately like below

```
String startTime = "2013-02-27 06:06:30";

StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(startTime);
String date1 = token.nextToken();  
String time1 = token.nextToken();
```

and in time1 I am getting the result 06:06:30,

Can I re-store it in another variable of type String as follows?

```
String displayValue = "06:06 AM";
```

And if time1 variable has the value of

```
String time = 16:00:00;
```

then it should be converted to:

```
String displayValue = "04:00 PM";
```

Comment: //Capitalize AM-PM//
fun String.capitalizeTime(): String {
    return this.replace("am", "AM").replace("pm", "PM")
}

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I got answer just doing like this.

```
startTime = "2013-02-27 21:06:30";
StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(startTime);
String date = tk.nextToken();  
String time = tk.nextToken();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat sdfs = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Date dt;
try {    
    dt = sdf.parse(time);
    System.out.println("Time Display: " + sdfs.format(dt)); // <-- I got result here
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This answer shows wrong time if your time is xxxx-xx-xx 12:30:00
it shows 12:30 AM instead 12:30 PM

Comment: @BhavikMehta Yes, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @MehulRanpara : there are a lot of solutions already given on StackOverFlow, just search around

Comment: Thank you. so much for help

Comment: I also had the same issue as Bhavik Metha. See my answer for the sollution

Comment: While the formatting is correct, your parsing isn’t. I tried with `startTime = "2013-02-27 12:06:30";` and expected 12:06 **PM**. But I got `Time Display: 12:06 AM`.

Answer (score 72):

Try this..

```
Date dt = new Date(date1);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
String time1 = sdf.format(dt);
```

Answer (score 22):

First you don't need to use `StringTokenizer` to get the string time. Just pass your `startTime` like this:

```
// Get date from string
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = dateFormatter.parse(startTime);

// Get time from date
SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
String displayValue = timeFormatter.format(date);

// Done!
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
 String time = "22:35";

try {
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
     Date dateObj = sdf.parse(time);
    System.out.println(dateObj);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm").format(dateObj));
} catch (final ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Trace out this link http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I was getting confusion hw i can convert 18:00:00 PM to 06:00:00 PM.. Thank you..By using "KK:mm:ss aa" i got result :)

Comment: Excellent solution.Thanks.

Comment: @androidlearner you might be using `HH:mm:ss aa` . Instead use `hh:mm:ss aa` for 12 hour AM-PM format

Answer (score 10):

```
Date dt = new Date(date1);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
String time1 = sdf.format(dt);
```

output 2.00 a.m.

```
 Date dt = new Date(date1);
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a",Locale.US);
 String time1 = sdf.format(dt);
```

output 2.00 AM

Comment: Should be SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a",Locale.US);

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using a DateFormat, like [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
try {
    String timeLong = "2013-02-27 06:06:30";
    String timeShort = "16:06 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat formatLong = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat formatShort = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.US);
    Log.v("out", formatShort.format(formatLong.parse(timeLong)));
    Log.v("out", formatShort.format(formatShort.parse(timeShort)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am tired today and I feel like I am missing something in this code so I might amend it later, but it does work and it doesn't (directly) call the deprecated Date class.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I tried but no use. Its showing  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 6):

1 Assuming you need to show the current time in the format **09:30 PM**. This would be a fairly easy approach. Even if you don't require it for the current time, you should be able to use the below DateFormat for your requirement.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm a");
String formattedTime = outputFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

2 **Note:** The following formatter can be used to display the same time in 24-hour format (**21:30**).

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

3 However, if you want to construct the same format as in my first point, it is best to use the following code as **Java discourages** the use of **StringTokenizer**. You can read about it here, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Hope this would help you, thanks!

```
    String startTime = "2013-02-27 21:06:30";
    String[] parts = startTime.split(" ");

    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm a");
    SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");


    try {
        Date dt = parseFormat.parse(parts[1]);
        System.out.println(outputFormat.format(dt));
    } catch(ParseException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Just use the following pattern you will get your expected result:**

```
    try {
        String time = "06:06:30";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        Date dt = sdf.parse(time);

        SimpleDateFormat sdfs = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String formatedTime = sdfs.format(dt);

        Log.v("parseTime", formatedTime);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: It seems to repeat what is in the accepted answer (which BTW isn’t fully correct)? Also in 2019 consider not using `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead you may add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Selected answer had an issue of showing wrong time. If your time is **12:30:00** it shows **12:30 AM** instead **12:30 PM**. The below code will help to overcome the issue.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat sdfs = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

    Date dt1 = null;

    try {
        dt1 = sdf.parse("12:00:00");
        Log.i("Time in Am Pm  ", sdfs.format(dt1));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On Android you also have [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)