# Not able to properly display time in AM, PM format in Android

Tags: java, android

I have achieved time formate using AM-PM by below code

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("h:m").parse((mHour+":"+mMinute));
String newString = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(date);
System.out.println("Time - "+newString);
```

but in above code there is one problem

If I set time **12:00 AM** in `TimePickerDialog` it will display **12:00 AM** but if I change time in `TimePickerDialog` to **12:00 PM** it will still display **12:00 AM**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert time value to format “hh:mm Am/Pm” using Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084474/convert-time-value-to-format-hhmm-am-pm-using-android)

Comment: are you using this code inside OnTimeSetListener ?

Comment: Just try this instead of `hh` use `h`  `String newString = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(date);`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava how can you say that it is duplicate?, I am getting problem in AM-PM, I have already achieve showing in  AM-PM

Comment: @MohitShrivastava, I want to show 08 that's why I have used 'hh' instead of 'h'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `h` is for **12 hour time format**. And your `TimePickerDialog` is sending you a `24` hour format.

Use,

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("H:m").parse((mHour+":"+mMinute)); // Upper H here.
```

### EDIT:

[SimpleDateFormat java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), Check out the **Date and Time Patterns** section.

Comment: thanks a lot :) would you share me it's docs link so in future also I can understand that where should I have to use "H" or 'h" like thath

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit, added to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**hh** which is the **1-12 hour format**. Try using capital **HH**, which uses 0-23 format.

**" HH:mm"**

so use

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse((mHour+":"+mMinute));
```