# How to parse time (hour, minute) from a string?

Tags: java, jodatime, datetime-format, android-jodatime

Anybody know how to parse time (hour, minute and AM/PM) from a string that looks like "01:20" -> 1:20AM and "21:20" -> 9:20PM? Most solutions out there seem to assume or require a Date or Calendar object.

My input time is actually coming from a TimePickerDialog (specifically, [this MaterialDateTimePicker implementation](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker), so I receive only the hourOfDay, minute and seconds (integers).

I want to be able to format the time that the user picked in a friendly way, i.e 12:30PM, 02:15AM, etc.

I am trying to use Joda Time:

```
fun formattedTime(timeStr: String): String {
    // Get time from date
    val timeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mm a")
    val displayTime = timeFormatter.parseLocalTime(timeStr)
    return displayTime.toString()
}
```

but I get this error with an input string such as "1:20":
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1:20" is too short`

I have also looked into [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) but it seems to require a full date-time string such as in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16084474/1145905)

Comment: If "01:20" should be interpreted as "01:20PM", then what should you enter if you want to get "01:20AM" ?

Comment: Do you want to parse a time string or format teh time as a string? I'm not sure when you're using the `MaterialDateTimePicker` you get the hours and minutes as integers why do you need to parse it?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt actually, "1:20" -> 01:20 AM and "13:20" -> 01:20 PM. i.e., TimePickerDialog returns hourOfDay values in the 0 -> 24 range

Comment: @kip2 Then why does your question read 'like "01:20" -> 1:20**PM** ' ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt my fault, I've edited the question.

Comment: @xander I could have done the formatting myself since I have the ints handy, but thought that using the standard/official libs would be a better approach since they're already built & tested :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @ole-v-v pointed out, `SimpleDateFormat` has seen better days - so today you can make use of the java.time package to do the job:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter target2 = 
     java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a");
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter source2 = 
     java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

System.out.println("01:30 -> " + target2.format(source2.parse("01:30")));
System.out.println("21:20 -> " + target2.format(source2.parse("21:20")));
```

Yields the result of

```
01:30 -> 1:30 AM
21:20 -> 9:20 PM
```

as expected.

In Joda-Time you would code it as @meno-hochschild pointed out in his answer below.

Using `SimpleDateFormat` it will look like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    System.out.println("01:30 -> " + target.format(source.parse("01:30")));
    System.out.println("21:20 -> " + target.format(source.parse("21:20")));
```

This will parse from 24h times to 12 hours display

```
    01:30 -> 1:30 AM
    21:20 -> 9:20 PM
```

It all depends on the format for the hours - for parsing you'll want 24h hours (format HH), for output you want 12 hours plus am / pm - format is h.

If you want 01:30 to be PM you'll have to add that to the string to be parsed somehow:

```
   System.out.println("01:30 pm-> " + target.format(target.parse("01:30 pm")));
```

resulting in

```
   01:30 pm-> 1:30 PM
```

Comment: works beautifully! I didn't need to add in the am/pm string to the input as the hourOfDay is in the range (0, 23)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Joda-Time (used in the question) is better. And today we have still better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct. However, I am astonished to see the old classes like `SimpleDateFormat` although the OP has explicitly first desired a Joda answer (see the tags of the question). So I post here the Joda answer as supplement:

```
DateTimeFormatter target = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mm a").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTimeFormatter source = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
System.out.println("01:30 -> " + target.print(source.parseLocalTime("01:30")));
System.out.println("21:20 -> " + target.print(source.parseLocalTime("21:20")));
```

> 01:30 -> 1:30 AM
>     21:20 -> 9:20 PM

I advise not to mix two different time libraries (the OP obviously uses Joda-Time-Android).

Answer (score 1):

Your two good options are Joda-Time and `java.time`.

Since you receive hourOfDay, minute and seconds as integers from the time picker, you don’t need to do any parsing.

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(Locale.US);
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(hourOfDay, minute, second);
    String displayTime = time.format(timeFormatter);
    System.out.println(displayTime);
```

This prints the time like this:

> 11:45 PM

Rather than an explicit format pattern string I am relying on the built-in localized format for the US locale. It has put a space between the minutes and `PM` (or `AM`). I believe your users will be happy about that. If not, you will need to use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma", Locale.US)` instead.

### Joda-Time

If you are already using Joda-Time and don’t have a reason for changing at this point, sticking to it is reasonable. You may use the `LocalTime(int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour, int secondOfMinute)` constructor. Then proceed as in [Meno Hochschild’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49902120/5772882). It’s a good and knowledgeable answer.

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to `java.time` (JSR-310).

(Quoted from [the Joda-Time homepage](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/))

### Stay away from SimpleDateFormat

Stay far away from the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It can be made to work for the job, but it is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.