# Java regex to fetch HH:MM:SS from a string

Tags: java, regex, time, timeofday

`String time = "Thu Dec 22 01:12:22 UTC 2022";`

How to fetch the HH:MM:SS (`01:12:22`) here using java regex .
So the output should be 01:12:22
I am using the below code but its not working.

```
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    String time = "Thu Dec 22 01:12:22 UTC 2022";
    String pattren = "(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattren);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(time);
    System.out.println("h");

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: There is no group 1 in your pattern, it should be `System.out.println(m.group());`

Comment: Why regex, just use DateTime api to parse the DateTime string and then get whatever you want.

Comment: @anubhava beat me to it. Don't rely on regex when you have actual APIs to do the job.

Comment: Start with `ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz y", Locale.ROOT));`. After that you may do either `zdt.toLocalTime()` or `zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"))`. Either results in `01:12:22`,

Comment: If you want help with the code you already have, please tell us in what way it fails? What are you seeing instead of the expected `01:12:22`? Paste it into the question.

Comment: Warning: Your string could contain other time zone abbreviations than `UTC`. If you assume that it is always UTC, you should validate this assumption. If you can’t be sure, you should convert the `ZonedDateTime` to UTC or which time zone you want before extracting the time as shown. In the worst case your string contains an *ambiguous* time zone abbreviations, they are many, and you won’t know what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is overkill here.

## `String#split`

You could simply [split the string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) by SPACE character, and take the fourth piece of text. Access the fourth piece with an index of three.

```
String timeText = input.split( " " )[ 3 ] ;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ZIwtLJ).

> 01:12:22

---

Or, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v), you could parse the entire string as a *java.time* object. Then extract the `LocalTime`. For this approach, see the [Answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74892880/642706), and the [Answer by hc_dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74892843/642706).

Answer (score 5):

### Regex is not the right tool for your requirement

As also suggested by anubhava and Basil Bourque, the best tool to use here is date-time API.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Thu Dec 22 01:12:22 UTC 2022";
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss VV uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, parser);
        LocalTime time = zdt.toLocalTime();
        System.out.println(time);

        // Or get the string representation
        String strTime = time.toString();
        System.out.println(strTime);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
01:12:22
01:12:22
```

**An important piece of advice from Ole V.V.**: If the time substring has zero seconds e.g. `01:12:00`, the default implementation of [`LocalTime#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#toString--) removes the trailing `:00`. In that, you will need a formatter also to format the time.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Thu Dec 22 01:12:00 UTC 2022";
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss VV uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, parser);
        LocalTime time = zdt.toLocalTime();

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strTime = time.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(strTime);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
01:12:00
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: The Trail links to a useful official tutorial. To apply credits correctly, this answer is rather applying Ole's comments for API, than Basil's answer with `split`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Good point! I will incorporate it soon.

Answer (score 3):

Not as simple (KISS) like [Basil suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74892560/5730279), but using *Java's Time API* elaborating on [Ole's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74892396/java-regex-to-fetch-hhmmss-from-a-string/74892843#comment132166505_74892396):

#### Steps using parser and temporal-query

Use [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method:

```java
String givenTime = "01:12:22";
String textWithTimeInside = "Thu Dec 22 "+ givenTime +" UTC 2022";

// create a formatter and parser for the given format
DateTimeFormatter timeParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz y", Locale.ROOT);

// parse the given text
var temporalParsed = timeParser.parse(textWithTimeInside);

// debug print the output of parsed Temporal (interface)
System.out.println(temporalParsed);

// extract time-part using a query
LocalTime localTime = temporalParsed.query(LocalTime::from);
System.out.println(localTime);

assert localTime.toString().equals(givenTime);
```

Prints:

```
{InstantSeconds=1671671542},ISO,UTC resolved to 2022-12-22T01:12:22
01:12:22
```

Run the [demo on IDEone](https://%20https://ideone.com/j5X45a).

#### Shortcut

Using method `parse(CharSequence text, TemporalQuery<T> query)` directly:

```
LocalTime localTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz y", Locale.ROOT)
    .parse("Thu Dec 22 01:12:22 UTC 2022", LocalTime::from);
```

#### See also

- [How to parse time (hour, minute) from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895929/how-to-parse-time-hour-minute-from-a-string) (also contains an answer from Ole V.V.)

Java Docs:

- [`TemporalQueries`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalQueries.html#localTime--), various predefined queries, e.g. for `LocalTime`
- [`TemporalQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalQuery.html), explains how the query works

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as stated.

As the first comment to the OPs question pointed out, there is a problem with the call to group. There is no group with index 1 in the pattern.

When running the code, java tells you the same:

```
~/src $ java test.java
Hello, World!
h
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:646)
    at test.main(test.java:14)
```

So with either no argument (as suggested by 4th bird), or 0 as argument (shown below), the code works as intended:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    String time = "Thu Dec 22 01:12:22 UTC 20\22";                                              
    String pattren = "(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattren);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(time);
    System.out.println("h");

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
    return;
}
}
```