# How to can convert Sting time value in 00:00:00 format?

Tags: android, string

I have one String

String time = 1 hour 37 minutes
How can I convert this time into 1:37:00 format in android?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084474/convert-time-value-to-format-hhmm-am-pm-using-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert time value to format “hh:mm Am/Pm” using Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084474/convert-time-value-to-format-hhmm-am-pm-using-android)

Comment: There is no am/pm mentioned in question, he is using hours and minutes.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad she is using hours and minutes

Comment: @NileshRathod Exactly, she is using hours and minutes but as String. She is not using Date object which can have am/pm when fetched in proper format.

Comment: i need only hour and minute like 00:00:00 format not required Am/Pm

Comment: @CopsOnRoad than she need to use this`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");`

Comment: I get time always in this format  x hour and  y minute so how can i convert into proper format

Comment: @krupagevariya Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387371/how-to-convert-minutes-to-hours-and-minutes-hhmm-in-java

Answer (score 0):

1)first step remove space from string (string = "1 hour 37 minutes)

```
   text = string.replace(" ", "");
```

2) Second step replace hour to ":" and minutes by ":00"

```
text = text.replace("hour",":");
      text = text.replace("minutes",":00");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must code a function that format your string  into what you need. Your function should be like this:

```
public static String formatTime(String inputTime)
{
String result = inputTime.replace(" ","");
result = result.replace("hours",":").replace("hour",":").replace("minutes","").replace("minute","");
String[] resultAux = result.split(":"); //First position will be hours, second position will be minutes

for(int i=0; i<resultAux.length; i++)
{
    if(resultAux[i].length() == 1)
    {
        resultAux[i] = "0" + resultAux[i]; //If we have 1 character in minutes we put the 0
    }
}

return String.join(":",resultAux) + ":00"; //Due to in your example you don't mention that you can have miliseconds we just put the miliseconds at the end


}
```

Of course you will call your function like this:

```
System.out.println("result is: " + formatTime("2 hours 37 minutes"));
```